# MailChimp API 2.0 timezone

Tags: php, time, mailchimp, schedule

I'm using the MailChimp API to create campagins from my own site. This all works perfectly but for the time.

When I schedule my campaign for say 9:00 PM it will be listed in MailChimp for 11:00 PM. And it wil be send at 11:00 PM as well.

My account settings are set to Central Europe GMT +2 and my server time echo's te correct time as well.

This is my code:

```
$schedule = $mailchimp->call('campaigns/schedule', array(
   'cid' =>  $campaign['id'],
   'schedule_time' => $date // format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer from MailChimp:**

> When passing the time through the campaigns/schedule call, it will be
>   formatted as GMT, as it mentions in the docs.
>
> Since the account is GMT+2, the campaign is scheduled for the GMT time
>   passed in the call, plus the offset for the account, which is causing
>   the two hour difference.
>
> Passing the time in the call as GMT will allow for the campaign to be
>   scheduled as expected.

This works :)